# how to check if my cloud firestore collection contains contains any documents

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to check if my firestore collection "payments" contains any documents where the string userActive is contained in any document field array called participants,and if it doesn't perform an action or if it does perform a different action, this is what i have tried so far but its not working

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wallet_app/send.dart';
import 'package:wallet_app/send_money.dart';
import 'package:wallet_app/recieve.dart';
import 'package:wallet_app/load.dart';
import 'package:wallet_app/account.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'package:wallet_app/CardScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';


class HomeScreener extends StatefulWidget{
  HomeScreen createState()=> HomeScreen();
}


class HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreener> {
    HomeScreen createState() => HomeScreen();
    

  final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  
  
  
  
  var userId = "dAIdrQggsrxvQ4KUo2aJ";

  var userActive = "kim";
  var userHasData = 0;


checkDatabase()async {


final docSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('payments')
        .where('participants', arrayContains: userActive)
        .getDocuments();

    if(docSnapshot.documents.isEmpty) {
       // Your queried documents do not exist
          userHasData = 1;
   }
   else if(docSnapshot.documents.isEmpty){
         // Your queried documents do not exist
   }

   userHasData = 2;     
}
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Container for top data
          Container(

            
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 32),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Hello " + "$userActive", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),

                    Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),

                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                         // Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.lightBlue[100],),
                          SizedBox(width: 16,),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 25,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: ClipOval(
                              child: Image.asset("assets/newdp.png", fit: BoxFit.contain,), 
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),

                Text("What would you like to do today?", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.blue[100]),),

                SizedBox(height : 40,),

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(243, 245, 248, 1),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18))
                            ),
                            child:IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.blue[900], size: 30,),
                              onPressed: () { 



                                
                                       Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => sendPager()),
            );
          },

                              
                              
                            ), 
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Text("Send", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 14, color: Colors.blue[100]),),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(243, 245, 248, 1),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18))
                            ),
                            child:IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance, color: Colors.blue[900], size: 30,),
                              onPressed: () { 



                                
                                       Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loadPager()),
            );
          },

                              
                              
                            ), 
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Text("Account", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 14, color: Colors.blue[100]),), 
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(243, 245, 248, 1),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18))
                            ),
                            child:IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.people, color: Colors.blue[900], size: 30,),
                              onPressed: () { 



                                
                                       Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loadPager()),
            );
          },

                              
                              
                            ), 
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Text("Recipients", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 14, color: Colors.blue[100]),),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(243, 245, 248, 1),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18))
                            ),
                            child:IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.blue[900], size: 30,),
                              onPressed: () { 



                                databaseReference.collection("payments").add(
  {
    "amount_paid" : "2444242",
    "amount_received" : "33535",
    "currency_received" : "¥",
    "currency_sent" :"K",
     'date':FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      "participants" :["kim", "john"  ],
            "receiver_name" : "john",
      "sender_name" : "kim"

    
  }).then((value){
    print("================================sucess=============================================================");
    print(value.documentID);
  });



                                
                                       Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loadPager()),
            );
          },

                              
                              
                            ), 
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Text("Invite", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 14, color: Colors.blue[100]),),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )

              ],
            ),
          ),
          
                    //draggable sheet
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            builder: (context, scrollController){
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(243, 245, 248, 1),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(40), topRight: Radius.circular(40))
                ),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 24,),
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Recent Transactions", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 24, color: Colors.black),),
                            Text("See all", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey[800]),)
                          ],
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 24,),

                      //Container for buttons
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: Text("All", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey[900]),),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[200], blurRadius: 10.0, spreadRadius: 4.5)]
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 16,),
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 8,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 8,
                                  ),
                                  Text("Recieved", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey[900]),),
                                ],
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[200], blurRadius: 10.0, spreadRadius: 4.5)]
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                            ),

                            SizedBox(width: 16,),
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 8,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 8,
                                  ),
                                  Text("Transfer", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey[900]),),
                                ],
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[200], blurRadius: 10.0, spreadRadius: 4.5)]
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: 16,),
                      //Container Listview for expenses and incomes
                      Container(
                        child: Text(" ", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[500]),),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
                      ),                      
                   

                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                            
                    StreamBuilder( 
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("payments").where('participants', arrayContains: userActive).snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot){


                                     checkDatabase();
                     

                      return Container ( child:ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        controller: ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                          DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.docs[index];

                          

                        //if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active && snapshot.hasData) {
                           if(userHasData == 1){
                               print(" no Data!!!");
                             return Center(child: Text("No Data"));
                             
                             
                             }
                          
                                    
                        
                          
                            else if (userHasData == 2){ 
                            
                            
                            print("Found Data!!!");

                          if(documentSnapshot.data()["receiver_name"] == userActive )  {         
                                                            

                                                              
                            return Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32,vertical: 5),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18))
                                  ),
                                  child: Icon(Icons.attach_money, color: Colors.lightBlue[900],),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                ),

                                SizedBox(width: 16,),
                                Expanded(
                                  
                                  child: Column(


                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      
                                    Text("Recieved", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[900]),) ,

                                    
                                   
                                      Text("" + documentSnapshot.data()["currency_received"] + documentSnapshot.data()["amount_received"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[500]),),
                                   

                                   
                                     
                                                                      
                                   
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),

                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[

                                    


                                    Text("+ " + documentSnapshot.data()["currency_sent"] + documentSnapshot.data()["amount_paid"].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.lightGreen),),



                                
 Text(documentSnapshot.data()["date"].toDate().toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[500]),),                                
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );


                      }else if (documentSnapshot.data()["sender_name"] == userActive){



                     return Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32,vertical: 5),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18))
                                  ),
                                  child: Icon(Icons.attach_money, color: Colors.lightBlue[900],),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                ),

                                SizedBox(width: 16,),
                                Expanded(
                                  
                                  child: Column(


                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      
                                    Text("Sent", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[900]),) ,

                                    
                                   
                                      Text("" +  documentSnapshot.data()["currency_received"] + documentSnapshot.data()["amount_received"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[500]),),
                                   

                                   
                                     
                                                                      
                                   
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),

                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[

                                    


                                    Text("- " + documentSnapshot.data()["currency_sent"] + documentSnapshot.data()["amount_paid"].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.orange),),



                                
                                                 Text(documentSnapshot.data()["date"].toDate().toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.grey[500]),),
                                
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );








                        
                 



                      }










    
                         }
    
    
    
    
  //  }    return Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator());


                          
                                    
                                                              }



                                                            
                       
                        

                        
                       )
                      );
                        
 }
 



  
   ),
                 

               

                    ],
                  ),
                  controller: scrollController,
                ),
              );
            },
            initialChildSize: 0.65,
            minChildSize: 0.65,
            maxChildSize: 1,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.exists` :

```
final docSnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('payments').document("document_id").get();

   if (docSnapshot.exists){
        //document exists
   }
   else{
        //document does not exists 
   }
```

---

for all documents:

```
final doc = await Firestore.instance.collection('payments').getDocuments();
    
       if (doc.documents.isEmpty){
            //Collection is empty 
       }
       else{
            //collection has documents
       }
```

You can apply the logic before using it in the element, like on start of the class then use `futureBuilder`. You can set a `bool` using the above logic and then using the `visibility` widget to show the `futureBuilder`  only if the document is available.

---

For your case:

```
final docSnapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('bus_information_user')
        .where('participants', arrayContains: userActive)
        .getDocuments();
    if(docSnapshot.documents.isEmpty){
       // Your queried dosuments does not exist
   }
   else{
         // Your queried dosuments does exist
   }
```

**Ps:.** I have not tried out the last part but should do the job.

Comment: i have tried but im still confused,  i just added my entire code to my question, would appreciate the help,

Comment: any luck on the help?